# TFS Power tools installed?

Tags: c#, tfs

How do I check if TFS Power tools is installed ?
I have been asked to check if TFS Power tools is installed.
I cant find it in control panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might I suggest that if you're not seeing it in control panel (by which I assume you mean the Programs and Features area, or whatever name it's got on whatever version of Windows you're using) that it's not installed.

This is my machine, searching for Power, with all power tools from 2008 - 2013 installed:

[image]

Of course, it would be nice if Microsoft didn't switch around the name they use for them.

---

Also, worth mentioning (since Pranay mentioned the Explorer extension) that, just because "TFS power tools" are installed, that doesn't mean that any particular *one* of the tools have been installed. The installer may have been used and a custom installation performed so that, say, only one of the tools has actually been installed; that still counts as the TFS Power tools being installed - so you might have to re-run the installer to get the specific tool you're looking for added.

Answer (score 2):

The 2010 version install a folder in the startup menu:

[image]

I *think* the 2013 version does too but they don't play well on the same system and so I am currently only running the 2010 version.

Comment: All versions of the power tools (or at least, from 2008 to 2013, I don't have 2005 installed nor 2015) install a folder into the start menu (by default).

Comment: I was pretty sure it did I just don't have an easily accessible env at the moment to be sure. From memory though I thought it did.